# Reading strings and integers into arrays from .txt file

Tags: c++, arrays

I am a novice programmer and I'm having trouble with one of my exercises. I need to create a program that reads the student information (SSN, First & last name, test score) from a .txt file called "students.txt", and then uses four global parallel arrays to store the student information. I'm required to use an int array to store SSN, a string array to store first names, a string array to store last names, and a double array to store scores. The operations include listing the students' info like this exactly how it appears:

```
   SSN     Last-Name  First-Name Score
628130189  James,     Paul        92.0
237698211  Cook ,     Daniel      86.0
201895367  Garza,     Melessa     78.0
491066285  Barbara,   Jessica     62.0
168606868  Bruce,     Elizabeth   90.0 
378205732  Lee,       Sarah       91.5
118453900  Brian,     David       87.0
583192186  Garza,     Cody        92.0
226665118  Lewis,     Gage        78.0
175382843  Collins,   James       69.5
816231095  White,     Ann         88.5
376651608  Jackson,   Mark        72.0
508234567  Freeman,   Mark        86.0
763211099  William,   Jack        52.0
286204723  Rodriguez, John        69.5
```

But of course, the .txt file is just SSN First-name last-name and score unaligned and separated by comas. Then I have to display the student with the highest score, and then the lowest, and the average of all scores using "void". I just dont know how to get it to read the file in the first place and make the data so that it's organized into columns.

Also...I have to report an error message and exit the program immediately if the file cannot be found? Otherwise, the program should display a main menu as follows to allow the user to complete the listed
operations.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std; 

void mainmenu();
/*
void sort_name();();
void sort_ssn();
void sort_score ();
*/
void average(); 
void lowest_score();
void highest_score();
void open_file();

const int totNum = 15; //my global variables
int ssn[totNum];
string fname [totNum];
string lname [totNum];
double score [totNum];

int main ()
{


    char choice;

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("students.txt")

for (1=0; i <= totNum; i++)//this is where I'm stuck
{
     ?????



}
do
{   mainmenu(); //calling main menu funtion
    cin >> choice;
    cin.ignore (10, '\n'); //spacing
    switch(choice) // switch statment for multiple cases for flexibility
    {
        case 'l':
        case 'L':
        case '1': open_file(); break; 
        /*
        case 'h':
        case 'H':   
        case '2': highest_score(); break; 
        case 'o':
        case 'O':
        case '3': lowest_score(); break;
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
        case '4': average(); break;

        case 's':
        case 'S':   
        case '5': sort_ssn(); break; //operation 5-7 is a bonus work
        case 'n':
        case 'N':
        case '6': sort_name(); break;
        case 'c':
        case 'C': 
        case '7': sort_score();break;
        */
        case 'e':
        case 'E':   
        case '0': break;
        default: cout << "Wrong choice!" << endl; break;    
    }
    cout << endl;
}   while(choice != '0'); // && choice !='E' && choice!='e')    
}
void mainmenu() //output main menu
{
cout << "Main Menu (Assignment 8)" << endl;
cout << "1. List students' infromation (L)" << endl;
/*
cout << "2. Find the highest score (H)" << endl;
cout << "3. Find the lowest score (O)" << endl;
cout << "4. Calculate the average score (A)" << endl;

cout << "5. Sort students by SSN (S)" << endl;
cout << "6. Dort students by name (N)" << endl;
cout << "7. Sort students by score (C)" << endl;
*/
cout << "0. Exit" << endl;
cout << "Please select an option: ";
}
```

it doesn't make any sense now but that's why I'm desperate for help...

Comment: You might be stuck at the line you say you are because it makes no sense at all: surely you mean `for (i=0; i <= totalNum; i++)`?

Comment: Yes, sorry I was kind of in a hurry.

Comment: but i guess you can say that that's the least of my problems lol